# Using lambda in Fixpoint Coq definitions

Tags: recursion, coq, dependent-type

I am trying to use `List.map` in recursive definition, mapping over a list using currently defined recursive function as an argument. Is it possible at all? I can define my own recursive fixpoint definition instead of using `map` but I am interested in using `map` here.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive D: nat -> Type := | D0 (x:nat): D x.

Inductive T: nat -> nat -> Type :=
| T0 {i o} (foo:nat): T i o
| T1 {i o} (foo bar:nat) : T i o -> T i o.

Fixpoint E {i o: nat} (t:T i o) (x:nat) (d:D i): option (D o) 
  :=
    (match t in @T i o
           return D i -> option (D o)
     with
     | T0 _ _ foo => fun d0 => None
     | T1 _ _ foo bar t' =>
       fun d0 =>
         let l := List.map (fun n => E t' x d0)  [ 1 ; 2 ; 3 ] in
         let default := Some (D0 o) in
         List.hd default l
     end) d.
```

The example above is artificial, but demonstrates the problem. The error message:

```
The term "l" has type "list (option (D n0))"
 while it is expected to have type "list (option (D o))".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to bind the names on the `T1` pattern:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive D: nat -> Type := | D0 (x:nat): D x.

Inductive T: nat -> nat -> Type :=
| T0 {i o} (foo:nat): T i o
| T1 {i o} (foo bar:nat) : T i o -> T i o.

Fixpoint E {i o: nat} (t:T i o) (x:nat) (d:D i): option (D o)
  :=
    (match t in @T i o
           return D i -> option (D o)
     with
     | T0 _ _ foo => fun d0 => None
     (*   \/ change here *)
     | T1 i o foo bar t' =>
       fun d0 =>
         let l := List.map (fun n => E t' x d0)  [ 1 ; 2 ; 3 ] in
         let default := Some (D0 o) in
         List.hd default l
     end) d.
```

The problem is that omitting the binders means that the `o` used on the `T1` branch refers to the "outer" variable of the same name, whereas you want it to refer to the one given by `T1`.

Comment: Thanks! This was weird. I was trying this earlier and it was generating new variable names (i0, o0 instead of i,o). But in this example it works now. Perhaps it was effect of some enclosing code.